# Simple key/value database

Tags: javascript, ajax, database

I'm looking for a very(!) simple (server-side) key/value database which preferably has a REST API. It's used to cache some values in a javascript driven web application. Looking for a quick set up and easy ajax interaction.
Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: A server-side DB, easily accessible via JS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check out couch db:

http://couchdb.apache.org/docs/intro.html

Sounds about what you are looking for.

Comment: I have never used couchdb, is it comparable to mongodb?

Comment: It is very simmilar, but it seems to be tailored and specialized for the web environment, whereas Mongo seems to be a more general purpose document based DB.

Answer (score 3):

Also look at [MongoDb](http://www.mongodb.org). Here is the [RESTful](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Http+Interface) api which returns JSON.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe CouchDB?

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bfje5csISQ8

Answer (score 0):

Probably you've already solved your needs, but I'm posting here to help somebody else.

I needed something like that, so I've built this: KVStore.io, a simple key/value API based storage service.

You can find the API docs and easy ways to consume them here: https://www.mashape.com/lordkada/kvstore

Please note, it's still under heavy development (it's an alpha version...) but I'm using it to store some stuffs (like website marketing forms) and it's working nicely...